# angular file-saver - files are not seen locally saved after deploy

Tags: angular, save-as

A very weird thing - I built a node-express + angular app, using the 
'file-saver' package to locally save files based on blob reached from the server.
It is working perfectly in the development environment (files are downloaded to the download folder), but **after deploying** the app to integration server - I can't see the .xls (excel) downloaded files ("*.xml" files opened by the browser are working fine). I still see the loading icon while the data is being fetched from the server (I also see the execution of the relevant SP).

Here is the relevant part of the file save code:
XML_TYPE = 'application/xml; charset=windows-1255'; - no problem

EXCEL_TYPE = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8'; - problematic

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
public exportAsXML(xmlData: any, fileName : string ) //This is working fine
{
  var blob = new Blob([xmlData], {type: XML_TYPE })
  FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName + XML_EXTENSION);
}

private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void //Not seen downloaded
{
  const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {type: EXCEL_TYPE});
  FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  private saveFileToDisk(data, filename: string, contentType: string)
  {

    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = filename;// "Report.csv";
    link.click();
  }
```

Edit:
and for excel (.xlsx) files, you can pass contentType like that:

```
saveFileToDisk(data, filename, 'application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'))
```

Comment: Arthur Cam - thanks, but as I mentioned - "It is working perfectly in the development environment" -  I'm looking for an explanation\solution for not working after deploy it in prod configuration (reference to the dist folder and a change in the api path)

Comment: Oh sorry, I just thought it was a download issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for that problem was in the import of the package:
Instead of

```
import { Workbook, Row, Worksheet, Cell } from 'exceljs';
```

It should be:

```
import { Workbook, Row, Worksheet, Cell } from 'exceljs/dist/exceljs';
```